# Regex everything before three dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that splits a string (in javascript) after a dot (and some other punctuation marks) and takes everything before that.
When there are 3 consecutive points, he splits this 3 times. I would like the regex to only split after the last consecutive point.

This is the current regex: `/(?<=[.,?!])/`

**Now:**
Sentence one.| Sentence two.|.|.|

**Desired result:**
Sentence one.| Sentence two...|

**Example:**
https://regex101.com/r/Ld63r8/1

Comment: Try matching, `text.match(/[^.,?!]+[.,?!]+/g)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MXrMng/1).

Comment: Yes, this works better. But when the last sentence doesn't end with a punctuation mark, that sentence is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may *match* the substrings you need using

```
 text.match(/[^.,?!]+[.,?!]*/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/veyNOA/1).

**Pattern details**

- `[^.,?!]+` - 1 or more chars other than a `.`, `,`, `?` and `!`
- `[.,?!]*` - 0 or more `.`, `,`, `?` or `!` chars.

JS demo:

```js
var text = "This is match one. This is the second, and the third? I want this to be the fourth and last...";
console.log(text.match(/[^.,?!]+[.,?!]*/g));
```